# How to give file name in html-test runner in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Can anyone please help me how to give filename in html-test runner in python.
As it is generating file name randomly I want the name to be user defined as I want to email that particular file.

```
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Dmat_dir',verbosity=2,))
```

It is not accepting file name as any parameter...Please provide answer with proper syntax. I'm using python 3.6

Comment: source of this HTMLTestRunner? Which PyPi package are you using?

Comment: __author__ = "Wai Yip Tung"
__version__ = "0.8.3"

Answer (score 0):

They have an example on the very top which shows how to use a file

```
fp = open('my_report.html', 'wb')
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
            stream=fp,
            title='My unit test',
            description='This demonstrates the report output by HTMLTestRunner.'
            )
 unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

Comment: New to it brother...do i need to import something for file..as I'm getting file is not defined?

Comment: Use `open` instead.

Comment: hey i got the following error when i used it:
self.stream.writeln()
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\runner.py", line 26, in writeln
    self.write('\n') # text-mode streams translate to \r\n if needed
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: That means the runner is not compatible with Python 3.X and you need to fix those changes

Comment: no runner is compatible ...the only issue was to have second parameter as 'w' instead of 'wb' but the thing is now my code not going to that piece of code ...please see the the code in edited version of question